# How to make header bar for each TopTabs in react navigation V3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation V3 for my project and I want a separate header bar for each screen of toptabs, not a common header bar for every screen of top tab.

I tried to make it but Header bar is coming under the toptabs. Actually my project requirement is to have different buttons and title on every screen of top tabs.

I have made a example on expo please review and give a solution.

https://snack.expo.io/@mudabbir/navigation-example

Answer (score 0):

You can customize you header on each screen by using static navigationOptions like below (only class component)

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    headerTintColor: '#5F55B2',
    headerStyle: { height: 60 },
};
```

or

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerTitle: (
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Home</Text >
                    <Text>header</Text>
                </View >),
            headerRight: (
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-search' />
                    </Button>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-calendar' />
                    </Button>
                </View>
            ),
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'green' }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I can customize but problem is header bar is coming below of top tabs